# how to list uncovered pm/pl file in Devel::Cover's report

Tags: perl, devel-cover

My dir/files are like this:

```
/lib/a.pm
/lib/b.pm
/lib/c.pm
..
/lib/n.pm

/lib/start.pl
```

start.pl is an interactive program, it will call different pm based on my selection.

when I run start.pl with

```
Devel::Cover :  PERL5OPT=-MDevel::Cover /lib/start.pl
```

the output html report will list all the pms start.pl called. 
I want to list all pms. 
All, include those pms start.pl called ,and those without called.
This will help me to get what pm not use during my current test.

Can this be done by Devel::Cover??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not.  If no part of a module has been executed, Devel::Cover doesn't know about the module.

Comment: so the total data(like 100/10000) is not include uncovered pms, too?

Comment: I add the function myself.. not too hard ^^

Comment: @Tingting did you submit a patch btw?

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct Devel::Cover is used with prove to detect the coverage of your test.

You should write tests then you could use Devel::Cover.

Short tutorial (windows based): http://perl-node-interface.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/how-to-use-develcover.html

Official tutorial: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Cover/lib/Devel/Cover/Tutorial.pod